# Collectionview cells are not showing according to screen width

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

cells are not showing in particular order i need 3 cells in a row so tried `CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.3, height: 100)` but getting unrelated out put

**code:**

```
    class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let layOut = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layOut.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layOut.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    layOut.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
    layOut.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    layOut.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.3, height: 100)

    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layOut
    }
    }

    extension ViewController1: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TestCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionCell
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
    }
```

**Edit:** got rounded cell

```
    class TestCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var roundImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        roundImg.layer.cornerRadius = roundImg.frame.height / 2
        roundImg.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        roundImg.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    }
```

**then i got this weird out put:** here i need 3 cells in a row but here it shows weird out put, how to get 3 cells in

[image]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/732AA.png
```

Comment: Move `roundImg.layer.cornerRadius = roundImg.frame.height / 2` to `layoutSubviews`. Where you are doing it is far too soon for the frame to be set yet.

Comment: @HangarRash, yes its worked but need to add this as well `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` in `cellForItemAt` then got circle image

Comment: @HangarRash, i have tried like this `CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.3, height: 100)` still getting some time 2 sometimes 1 cell vertically why? how do i get 3 cells in screen width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things...

First, there is likely some issues with your constraints, as every thing is shifted to the right. You haven't shown us anything about your cell layout, so tough to say.

---

Second, during development, give your UI elements contrasting background colors to make it easy to see the framing.

For example, this:

[image]

gives you a ***LOT*** more information than this:

[image]

---

Third, you almost certainly want `layOut.scrollDirection = .vertical` instead of `layOut.scrollDirection = .horizontal`.

When set to horizontal scrolling, the collection view fills top-to-bottom, then left-to-right.

So, if you have only 10 items (as in your image), it will look like this:

[image]

but you likely want to *scroll vertically* (when you have lots of cells), and you want it to look like this with only 10 items:

[image]

---

Fourth, don't use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` ... if your app is running on an iPad in multi-tasking mode, you won't be even close to what you're going for.

Instead, use the frame of the collection view -- but when doing that we need to wait until the views have been laid-out. A good place for that is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, but we have to be careful since that will be called many times.

So, add a class-level property:

```
var cvWidth: CGFloat = -1.0

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // only do this if the collection view frame has changed
    if cvWidth != collectionView.frame.size.width {
        cvWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width
        if let fl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            // we have 5-points on each side from .sectionInset
            //  and 5-points between "columns"
            // so we want the cell width to be 1/3rd of the collection view width
            // minus the "space"
            let w = (cvWidth - 20.0) / 3.0
            fl.itemSize = .init(width: w, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

That will **sort of** work. We're dealing with floating-point though, so the values will not be exact, and we'll usually end up with only TWO columns fitting.

To fix that, change:

```
    layOut.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
```

to:

```
    layOut.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
```

That will allow the collection view to fit 3 "cell columns" and add just enough spacing between the items.

---

**Edit** - to make this a little more flexible, and allow for different number of columns...

```
var cvWidth: CGFloat = -1.0

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if cvWidth != collectionView.frame.size.width {
        cvWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width
        if let fl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            
            // number of columns to show - you might be setting this elsewhere
            let nColumns: Int = 4
            
            // get the left and right section inset values
            let sideSpace: CGFloat = fl.sectionInset.left + fl.sectionInset.right
            
            // we want *about* 5-points spacing between items
            let totalEmptyspace: CGFloat = sideSpace + (CGFloat(nColumns) * 5.0)
            
            // calculate item width for nColumns number of columns
            let w = (cvWidth - totalEmptyspace) / CGFloat(nColumns)
            fl.itemSize = .init(width: w, height: 100)

            // make sure interItemSpacing is set to Zero!
            fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0

        }
    }
}
```

With `nColumns = 4` we get this:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for all this information.. as you said i got 3 cells when i change `layOut.scrollDirection = .vertical` but my major question is how to calculate the number of cells count per line for eg., here we are getting 3 cells for example if i want 4 or 5 cell then how to calculate the width here `layOut.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.3, height: 100)` here if i change  `* 0.3 to  0.4 or 0.5` will this work or any particular way to get exact number of cells per width

Comment: here `let w = (cvWidth - 20.0) / 3.0` if i change / 4.0 then can i get 4 cells and / 5.0 then can i get 5 cells per width. this is my major doubt

Comment: @User123 - don't use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` ***at all*** ... See the **Edit** to my answer regarding 3, 4, 5 "columns"